# How to Call Subfolder Controller method in Routes in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

I have controllers in subfolders

```
--Controllers
----Admin
--------UserController
--------AccountController
----User
--------UserController
--------AccountController
```

I write routes for it

```
$routes->group('user', function ($routes){
    $routes->get('dashboard', 'UserDashboard::index');
    $routes->get('changePassword', 'User\AccountController::changePassword');
});
```

It give me 404 even though I have method and have something output as well

**Controller code**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello";
        exit();
        return view('user/account/changePassword');
    }

    public function changePassword()
    {
        echo "Change Password View";
        exit();
        return view('user/account/changePassword');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am curious as to why you have "public" in your URL. Can you explain why that is there?

Comment: I agree with @TimBrownlaw public shouldn't be in the url. Actually it would be best to not even work with localhost and work with a proper local domain like http://foo.local so you can better mimic the real environment.

Comment: It is solved because of using wrong namespace. @TimBrownlaw the public is because the index.php file is in the that folder it is not in the root folder

Comment: @marcogmonteiro thank you for the advice i followed the same you told and it is good now and very easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the namespace of your controllers.

User controllers

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\User;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    
}
```

Admin controllers

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir this was the main issue. Now it is solved